# href is not automatically generated when ui-sref is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use angular js ui router to route my page.

Here's the code that I've written:

```
<a  ui-sref="transporterEditDetails({companyId:  '{{d.companyId}}' )"  style="cursor: pointer">{{d.companyName}}</a>
```

Here's the js code :

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','xeditable','google.places','angular-loading-bar','ui.select','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','notificationsTruckway','ui.tinymce'])
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
 $stateProvider
        .state('transporterEditDetails', {
        url: '/transporterEditDetails/:companyId',
        controller:'TransporterEditDetailsController',
        templateUrl: 'Transporter-editDetails.html'
    })
routerApp.controller('TransporterEditDetailsController', function($scope,$location,$http,usersFactory,$stateParams) {
$scope.companyId = $stateParams.companyId;
}
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code, I'm unable to get the href attribute which should be generated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try without quotes and parentheses

```
<a  ui-sref="transporterEditDetails({companyId:  d.companyId})"  style="cursor: pointer">{{d.companyName}}</a>
```

Comment: I see, I'll remove the quotes and parentheses and check if its working.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `{{}}`(interpolation) inside `ui-sref`. Also remove `'`(wrapped single quote)

```
ui-sref="transporterEditDetails({companyId:  d.companyId })"
```

Comment: I'll give it a try.